# Wordpress get post meta add shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode, meta

my index post meta code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_option('page_on_front'), 'my_post_meta', true); ?>
```

my shortcode

```
function shortcode() {
   echo "cesa";
}
```

if shortcode I run it in content working.

```
index page echo cesa
```

but shortcode post meta run with, not working :(

```
index page only text [shortcode]
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes must be parsed, not simply echoed. You can do this by running the `the_content` filter over it:

```
$content = get_post_meta(get_option('page_on_front'), 'my_post_meta', true);
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Comment: One very important point - shortcodes should not `echo`, you must `return` the output!

Comment: @PeterHvD Regarding the shortcode callback function, that's true.